# No such device: grub rescue

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot

I have got a machine with Windows and Linux Mint. Now that I needed to upgrade my Mint because I needed the new fixes, I cannot boot. I get the error message `no such device, grub rescue`. My guess is that the disk id has been changed and grub cannot find it. I **do not remember** where I originally installed the grub. The output from `fdisk`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 256.1 GB, 256060514304 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 31130 cylinders, total 500118192 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x5e24ae5b

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   500115455   249954304    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x5e24ae82

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048   929521663   464759808    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2       929523710  1953523711   512000001    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sdb5       929523712  1887181915   478829102   83  Linux
/dev/sdb6      1887184896  1953523711    33169408   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

I have searched the forums and ran the `grub-install` on `/dev/sdb1`. Still getting the same error. However, during startup when I change the boot disk to the second one (`/dev/sdb1`), I am able to boot, and even to the old Windows I had. My yet another guess is that if I do `grub-install` on `/dev/sda1`, it will fix my problem, but I am hesitating doing so because I cannot and must not lose data on that partition.

So, my question is: Is it safe to do `grub-install /dev/sda`? How do I check if the old grub was installed there, the one that is not able to boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution: installed grub on the second disk and changed the order of boot device.